# Android recycleview is duplicating upon data update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

In `MainActivity`, I've:

```
lateinit var adapter: ChapterAdapter
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)

   userViewModel.allUsers.observe(this, Observer { users ->
       users?.let { it ->
             it?.forEach {
                 val insertIndex = chaptersList.size
                 chaptersList.add(insertIndex, it.toString())
                 adapter.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)
             }
         }
   })
}
```

In the `chapterAdapter`, I've:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, b ->
            Toast.makeText(context, b.toString(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            userViewModel.update(position, "AHasan")
          //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

    }
}
```

My `repository` is:

```
import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

    val allUsers: LiveData<List<User>> = userDao.getAll()

    @WorkerThread
    fun insert(user: User) {
        userDao.insertAll(user)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    fun update(id: Int, name: String) {
        userDao.updateById(id, name)
    }
}
```

The recycleView is updating correctly upon `insert`, but upon `ItemChanged` it is duplicating everything, i.e. all the cards in the `recycleView`, if I closed the app, and run it again, things are back to the correct situation

Comment: check our answers, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i had to guess why this happens, i'd say that your `userViewModel.update(position, "AHasan")` is updating this observer :

```
 userViewModel.allUsers.observe(this, Observer { users ->
       users?.let { it ->
             it?.forEach {
                 val insertIndex = chaptersList.size
                 chaptersList.add(insertIndex, it.toString())
                 adapter.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)
             }
         }
   })
```

and then all the items are added again. so, as a suggestion and possible fix, try clearing your list here:

```
 userViewModel.allUsers.observe(this, Observer { users ->
       users?.let { it ->
     //try clearing the adapters items here before adding them again
     //as John Joe said you can use 
        chaptersList.clear()
     // try updating your adapter here
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
             it?.forEach {
                 val insertIndex = chaptersList.size
                 chaptersList.add(insertIndex, it.toString())
                 adapter.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)
             }
         }
   })
```